# using python to remove extra characters from strings and remove two decimal places to make it an integer

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, replace

I want to extract the size of a property from a website. Part of the Code I have tried which is concerned with the extracted string is this

```
        try:
            size_result= str(value)
            print "Size of the property: ",size_result
        except StandardError as e:
            size_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
            print size_result
```

The output i get is a string with this format

```
7332.00 SqFt
```

All the outputs have a `.00` at the end which means its seven thousand three hundred and thirty two and has two decimals with is to make it 
    `7332.00 SqFt`

**What I want:**

An integer`7332` which means

1. remove SqFt
2. Remove two decimal
3. make it an integer to i can use it for computation in SQL

Comment: How did you get that output from that code? Your code would have output starting with "Size of the property: " or "Error was ".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split it on the point and convert to integer:

```
area = int(size_result.split('.')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
a = '7332.00 SqFt '
int(a[:a.find('.')])
```

The `find` parts looks for the dot (`.`), and it slices until that point, leaving only the value. Then cast it to an int by calling `int()`.

Comment: would it remove the decimal and return an integer?

Comment: @Panetta yes, because it would only read up untill the dot (not in cluding the dot).